# Encoding issues when inserting data to neo4j with python

Tags: encoding, neo4j

I have a python script which reads data from a CSV file and runs some cypher queries, which create nodes and relationships with properties.
My CSV file has several non latin characters. These characters are changed and they are not displayed correctly. 
Is there a way to change the encoding in neo4j?

Thanks 
D.

Comment: It seems the issue is caused by the CSV file. It has a different encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this:

```
              encoding='utf-8'
```

in my python script fixed the problem:

```
             fparts = open('FOC_NETWORK.csv',  encoding='utf-8')
             csv_pseudo = csv.reader(fparts)
```